# Netezza GOTO statement

Tags: netezza, nzplsql

I have a specific query. Can we implement GOTO logic in Netezza Stored Procedure. I need to implement a labelled block inside a netezza procedure. Then I want to execute a GOTO statement from inside the same procedure, which will jump and execute the labelled block. Can we achieve that. If possible, how?

Comment: Normally, you can avoid using `goto` by using other control flow functions, such a loops and `if` statements (although you might have to introduce additional variables).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of version 7.2, NZPLSQL does not support GOTO.  The control structures it does support include:

- IF-THEN-ELSE
- LOOP
- WHILE
- FOR
- EXIT